# Codeigniter undefined property on core/Model.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller

```
    public function editItem(){
         $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $this->load->model('ItemModel'); 
         $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist(); 
         $item_details = $this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));    
         $data2['item_name'] = $item_details->name; //THIS IS LINE 28
         $data2['item_description']= $item_details->description; 
         $data2['item_price'] = $item_details->price;
         $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data2); 
    }
```

There's an error to my view, and I don't know why

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Item::$name

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 77

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\itwa213\application\controllers\Item.php
Line: 28
Function: __get

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\itwa213\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I already checked my autoload on config and it's properly configured with

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: could you please copy and paste there your controllers function also

Comment: public function editItem(){
             $this->load->helper('form');
             $this->load->model('ItemModel');
             $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist();
             $item_details = $this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));

             $data2['item_name'] = $item_details->name;
             $data2['item_description'] = $item_details->description;
             $data2['item_price'] = $item_details->price;

             //now you can use the specific data to your view.
             $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data2);

        }

Comment: How does your url look when you have id in it?

Comment: show your `$this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));` code

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
public function editItem() {
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $this->load->model('ItemModel'); 

     $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist(); 

     $item_details = $this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));    

     $data2['item_name'] = $item_details['name']; //THIS IS LINE 28
     $data2['item_description'] = $item_details['description']; 
     $data2['item_price'] = $item_details['price'];

     $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller function change to like this

```
public function editItem(){ 
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->model('ItemModel');

  $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist(); 
  $data2['item_details'] =$this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id')); 

  $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data2); 
}
```

and in your view page

```
echo $item_details->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your code for the get function you use. try to replace the `$this->input->get('id')` to existing id number first. check whether it success or not. If success by using existed id number, so it should your get function not working or something wrong. i'm seldom use $this->input->get() but $this->input->post().

on your edit link, you can use:
`<a href="controller/method/id">edit</a>`. 
so the id is the third segment uri. use `$this->uri->segment(3);` to get the third segment and store into $item_id variable into your controller. so, no need to use $this->input->get(); to get the item_id value.